# Pragma in Select request

Tags: sql, sqlite, pragma

I wanna to retrieve column's names and rows count in a table in SQLite.
Is it possible to do this is one command?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename
```

and

```
PRAGMA table_info(tablename))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PRAGMA is a separate command, not a (sub)query, and cannot be combined with other SQL statements.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer was correct, but is now outdated, since SQLite 3.16.0 you can use [PRAGMA functions](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragfunc)

So you can now write:

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('tablename') JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename);
```

Or if you really only need the name:

```
SELECT name, rowcount FROM pragma_table_info('tablename') JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM tablename);
```

(tested in SQLite 3.25.2)

Use it at your own risk though:

> This feature is experimental and is subject to change. Further documentation will become available if and when the table-valued functions for PRAGMAs feature becomes officially supported.